# Git - Does a remote branch need to be pulled local to merge?

Tags: git

I have a local branch on which I committed some changes. I would then like to pull the changes that have been added to the parent branch by other developers. Do I need to pull down the parent branch locally before doing the `merge`?

I thought I had been bringing down changes made by other developers by just going to my dev branch and then issuing a `merge` command and selecting the remote branch. However, I don't think it actually pulled down the parent branch changes until I issued a `pull` to the parent branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically there are three different branches you should think of:

- your local branch (e.g. master) where you commit your changes to
- the branch on the remote server, where others push their changes to
- the remote branch (e.g. origin/master) in your local repository which you use to track the remote repository

After other people push their work to the remote repository, you need `git fetch` to update your remote branch in order to see those changes.

Afterwards you can use those changes to merge e.g. origin/master into master. And finally you can push the result back to the server.

You can do the fetch and merge in two commands or use `git pull` which is pretty much exactly the same as first a fetch an then a merge. (Also be aware of the `--rebase` option, which is a combination of fetch and rebase, which usually gives a much cleaner history.)

Comment: I'd add however that rebasing while producing a linear history, often is more complicated in terms of merge simplicity: one has to merge every commit in the local sequence with the upstream, and resolve changes in certain places multiple times. So I'd suggest ordinary merges for longer local branches.

Comment: Yes, it always depends. If you are working at some feature and did many commits to do so, an explicit merge would probably be best. (But in that case you would usually use some feature branch anyway.) If you just did a quick fix directly on the branch and don't expect any merge conflicts then use a rebase to avoid a meaningless merge commit.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run `git fetch` in order to fetch the changes that are available in a remote. You can then use `git merge` to perform the merge. `git pull` is a shortcut which performs both of these commands in succession.